# How to force Grafana to use my own units for the Y axis label despite of it detects units automaically from the Prometheus metrics name

Tags: prometheus, grafana, micrometer

We have `camel_proxy_some_name_getmessages_seconds_count` metrics and here the metrics units in none. But Grafana detects seconds automatically. When I switch unit from seconds to none, it ignores the change, still showing the time units with its not convinient base for checking large number of "seconds" like weeks and days.

[image]

[image]

How to work that around?

P.S

Override part is empty here:

[image]

Comment: Try using the `short` unit and check that there is no field overrides.

Comment: @anemyte where I can check for overrides? `short` is also not helping me

Comment: "Where" depends on Grafana and panel version, but I see "overrides" on one of your screenshots. It is possible to define the unit there as well.

Comment: @anemyte I have updated the question. Override is definitely empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update it to a needed unit here (red circle):

[image]